# Изменение свойства visibility для всех элементов с классом в конкретном блоке

Tags: javascript, hidden

Есть несколько блоков ('.projects__block') с одинаковыми дочерними элементами, классами и эффектом аккардион. В этом блоке есть элементы которые в изначальном состоянии скрыты ('.hide__block'), но когда срабатывает аккардион они должны перейти в состояние visible.

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="projects__block">
      <div class="projects__block__image accordion hide">
        <img src="{{project.img}}" alt="project cover">
        <span class="bg-color {{project.special_css}}">{{project.special}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="projects__block__main hide">
        <div class="projects__block__text">
          <span class="projects__block__time">{{project.date}}</span>
          <h3 class="projects__block__title">{{project.title}}</h3>
          <p class="projects__block__desc hide__block">{{project.desc}}</p>
          <span class="projects__block__done hide__block">{{project.done}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="projects__help-icons hide__block">
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon1}}"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon2}}"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon3}}"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon4}}"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <div class="projects__block">
      <div class="projects__block__image accordion hide">
        <img src="{{project.img}}" alt="project cover">
        <span class="bg-color {{project.special_css}}">{{project.special}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="projects__block__main hide">
        <div class="projects__block__text">
          <span class="projects__block__time">{{project.date}}</span>
          <h3 class="projects__block__title">{{project.title}}</h3>
          <p class="projects__block__desc hide__block">{{project.desc}}</p>
          <span class="projects__block__done hide__block">{{project.done}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="projects__help-icons hide__block">
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon1}}"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon2}}"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon3}}"></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="small-icon {{project.icon4}}"></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.projects__block {
overflow: hidden;
}
.projects__block__image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 32%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0;
}
.projects__block .accordion {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: .4s;
}
.projects__block .hide {
  max-height: 134px;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}
.projects__block__main {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 65%;
  padding-left: 4%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8992a7;
}
.projects__block__text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}
.projects__block__desc {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif,"Myriad Pro";
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
}
.projects__block__done {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 17px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif,"Myriad Pro";
  color: #6f7f9f;
}
.projects__help-icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  transition: visibility .3s ease-out;
}
.projects__block .hide__block {
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility .2s ease-out;
}
```

Сейчас все работает только для первого блока. Как сделать, чтобы '.hide__block' срабатывал в каждом родительском '.projects__block' отдельно?

**JS:**

```
  let acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
  let i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle('acc-active');
      let hide = this.nextElementSibling;
      let hideBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('hide__block');

      if (hide.style.maxHeight) {

        hide.style.maxHeight = null;

        (() => {
          for (let i = 0; i < hideBlock.length; i++) {
            hideBlock[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
        })();

      } else {

        hide.style.maxHeight = hide.scrollHeight + 'px';

        (() => {
          for (let i = 0; i < hideBlock.length; i++) {
            hideBlock[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
          }
        })();

      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: CSS бы тоже не помешал

Comment: @Cheg - добавил